# issue with printing the subprocess.run() call

Tags: python, jar, subprocess

I am facing a scenario where in I need to execute a jar based on user parameters. I have replicated the scenario here as below :

```
import subprocess

a = input('Enter either 2 or 3:')

value = int(a)
if a == 2:
    p1 = subprocess.run(['java', '-jar', 'SimpleClient.jar', '-info'], capture_output=True)

else:
    p1 = subprocess.run(['java', '-jar', 'SimpleClient.jar'], capture_output=True)

print('-----------stdout---------------------')
print(p1.stdout.decode())
print('-----------code---------------------')
print(p1.returncode)
```

What I observe is that the print function does not execute. I expect it to show different results based on my entry.

```
Enter either 2 or 3: 2

-----------stdout---------------------
-----------code---------------------
0
```

I had a doubt if p1 is only within the if and else scope. I put the print stattements even inside those clauses. But that does not help either.

Could anyone guide me here?

Comment: Are you sure that `java -jar SimpleClient.jar -info` prints something on stdout ? Maybe it prints only on stderr

Comment: @Didier you are right . I am observing all the log on stderr. Does this not mean that the jar is producing an error? I get some positive results in between too. How are those coming under stderr? Any explanation please

Comment: That would depend on what output you're seeing. You should be able to tell if it's an error based on what the message says.

Comment: so basically it will ouput a log on screen. We are performing testing for manyfeatures here. Some outputs are seen with log level INFO, some with WARNING etc. How is the INFO inside the error, I expect atleast to see that in the stdout